# jest testing react input text with max character limit inside component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

Got an input box inside a React functional component that has a max character limit of five characters. Is there a way to test this using jest?

- should prevent user from typing more than 5 characters
- should let user type in no more than 5 characters

Component:

```
const [nickname, setNickname] = useState("");

const setNicknameHandler = (value: string) => {
   if (value.length > 5) {
      return; 
   }
   setNickname(value);
}

return (
    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setNicknameHandler(e.target.value)} value={nickname}  />
)
```

Test:

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";


it("test", () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();

  const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);

  user.type(getByTestId(/my-input/i), "chocolatemoose");

  // chocolatemoose is greater than 5 characters so user shouldn't be able to type this, not sure how to test this though

})
```

Comment: You can avoid this by using native HTML input attributes, like the [maxLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength) attribute -- you just need to use "camelCase" because that's how React interpolates multi-word DOM attributes: so "maxlength" becomes "maxLength" and "minlength" becomes "minLength" and so on. Since this will now be handled natively, you won't need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The [`.type()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#type) API returns a promise, you should use `async/await` to wait for the promise resolved. When typing more than 5 characters, the state of the component will not be updated, and the input value is `choco`.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState('');

  const setNicknameHandler = (value: string) => {
    if (value.length > 5) {
      return;
    }
    setNickname(value);
  };

  return (
    <input data-testid="my-input" type="text" onChange={(e) => setNicknameHandler(e.target.value)} value={nickname} />
  );
};
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

describe('72072743', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<MyComponent />);
    await user.type(screen.getByTestId(/my-input/i), 'chocolatemoose');
    expect(screen.getByTestId(/my-input/i)).toHaveValue('choco');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72072743/MyComponent.test.tsx (11.052 s)
  72072743
    ✓ should pass (130 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.76 s, estimated 12 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0"
```